# dcm4che query at SOP instance level

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I want to query dcm4che on the local server for the metadata for all the images to do an inventory.
The problem is that when I run these three lines

```
./dcmqr  -L Myserver  Myserver@localhost:11112
./dcmqr  -L Myserver  Myserver@localhost:11112 -P
./dcmqr  -L Myserver  Myserver@localhost:11112 -S
```

I am able to retrieve an output of all the metadata of the dicoms on the local server, but when I run the command

```
./dcmqr  -L Myserver  Myserver@localhost:11112 -I
```

I receive error like this

```
09:11:07,781 INFO   - Myserver(1) << A-ABORT[source=0, reason=0]
09:11:07,852 INFO   - Myserver(1): close Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=11112,localport=45714]
09:11:07,854 WARN   - i/o exception in State Sta13
java.io.EOFException
        at org.dcm4che2.net.PDUDecoder.readFully(PDUDecoder.java:100)
        at org.dcm4che2.net.PDUDecoder.nextPDU(PDUDecoder.java:152)
        at org.dcm4che2.net.Association.run(Association.java:790)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
java.io.EOFException
        at org.dcm4che2.net.PDUDecoder.readFully(PDUDecoder.java:100)
        at org.dcm4che2.net.PDUDecoder.nextPDU(PDUDecoder.java:152)
        at org.dcm4che2.net.Association.run(Association.java:790)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
09:11:07,857 WARN   - unable to send A-RELEASE-RQ in state: Sta1
Released connection to Myserver@localhost:11112
```

Which it would crush the server leaving it unable to query anything else for about 5-10 minutes or so, during this time I am not able to restart the service as well but after a while, everything is working again and I can query everything except at the Image level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing an open query at the instance level (i.e. retrieve every single, individual instance in your archive). This is not advisable and if you have an archive of any reasonable size, it will cause issues.

If you do an instance level query, specify the study and series using the -q flag.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, except the whole dcm4chee went down on the server now and it is having problem restarting apparently that last query broke something internally and it is having trouble query with jboss